# How to receive blog post data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, fetch, content-management-system

I am receiving all blog posts from my "backend - headless CMS)" - all data are correct, but when I click on specific blog post, nothing is happening.

Each blog post has its own category that belongs to. This is how I fetch them.

```
const [doc, setDocData] = useState(null);
const [categoryOne, setCategoryOne] = useState([]);
const [categoryTwo, setCategoryTwo] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await client.query(
                Prismic.Predicates.at('document.type', 'post'),
                { pageSize: 100 }
            );
            if (result) {
                const oneArr = [];
                const twoArr = [];
                result.results.forEach((post) => {
                    switch (post.data.category[0].text) {
                        case 'CategoryOne':
                            oneArr.push(post);
                            break;
                        case 'CategoryTwo':
                            twoArr.push(post);
                            break;
                        default:
                            console.warn('Missing blog post category.');
                    }
                });
                setCategoryOne(oneArr);
                setCategoryTwo(twoArr);
                return setDocData(result);
            } else {
                console.warn(
                    'Not found'
                );
            }
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);
```

**And showing the data on frontend:**

```
        <h1>{post.data.title[0].text}</h1>
        <image src={post.data.image.url} />
        <Link to={'blog/' + post.slugs[0]}>BUTTON </Link>
```

When I click on `Link`, the url changes to the name of the blog post, which is corrent, but content of the page is still the same - it should change to the content of that specific post.

With React router I am doing something like this:

```
 <Route path={baseRouteUrl + 'blog/:slug'}
        component={(props) => <Post />}
 ></Route>
```

How can I achieve to be redirected to the correct post content after clicking on the Link?

Answer (score 0):

You should have 2 Route with props `exact` like this:

```
<Route exact path={"/blog"} component={Post}></Route>;

<Route exact path={"/blog/:slug"} component={PostDetail}></Route>;
```

Comment: Hey @VũHuyHoàng, thanks for the answer. It actually helped to redirect to the other page - but I am not sure how to achieve correct data receive of that specfic post I clicked on.